# Exercise 5 page 36 in Functional Analysis book of Conway

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is Exercise 5 page 36 in Functional Analysis book of Conway:

> Find the adjoint of a diagonal operator (Exercise 1.8).

The aforementioned exercise 1.8 read:

> Exercise 1.8. Let $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the usual basis for $l^2$ and let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of scalars. Show that there is a bounded operator $A$ on $l^2$ such that $Ae_n = a_n e_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded, in which case $||A|| =\sup{\{|a_n|: n \ge 1}\}$. This type of operator is called a diagonal operator or is said to be diagonalizable.

Well Exercise 1.8 is easy to solve but I am struggling with Exercise 5 : $\langle Ah,g \rangle = \langle h,A^*g \rangle \implies \langle A \sum b_n e_n, \sum c_n e_n \rangle = \langle \sum b_n a_n e_n ,c_n A^*e_n  \rangle$. Any calculation further than that looks not rigorous and correct.

Comment: Use $h=e_j$ and $g=e_k$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\langle Ah,g\rangle&=\langle \sum_na_nb_n\mathbf{e}_n,\sum_nc_n\mathbf{e}_n\rangle=\sum_na_nb_n\overline{c_n}\\
&=\sum_nb_n\overline{\overline{a_n}c_n}=\langle \sum_nb_n\mathbf{e}_n,\sum_n\overline{a_n}c_n\mathbf{e}_n\rangle\\
&=\langle h,A^*g\rangle
\end{align}$$
From this you can see that $A^*\mathbf{e}_k=\overline{a_k}\mathbf{e}_k$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the convention that inner product is linear on first coordinate and anti-linear on the second one. (To adapt the solution below to the other convention is trivial).

Let us prove that $A^*$ is the linear operator defined by $A^*e_n = \bar a_n e_n$.

\begin{align*} 
\langle Ah,g \rangle &= \langle A \sum b_n e_n, \sum c_m e_m \rangle = \\
&=  \sum_{n,m} b_n \bar c_m \langle A  e_n,  e_m \rangle = \\
& = \sum_{n,m} b_n \bar c_m \langle a_n  e_n,  e_m \rangle = \\  
& =  \sum_{n,m} b_n \bar c_m a_n  \langle   e_n,  e_m \rangle = \\  
& =  \sum_n b_n \bar c_n a_n   = \\  
& =  \sum_{n,m} b_m \bar c_n a_n  \langle   e_m,  e_n \rangle = \\ 
& =  \sum_{n,m} b_m \bar c_n   \langle   e_m, \bar a_n e_n \rangle = \\
&=  \langle  \sum b_m e_m, \sum c_n \bar a_n e_n \rangle  = \\
& = \langle h, A^*g \rangle
\end{align*}